# Number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+...+x_p=m$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+...+x_p=m$$ such that $x_k\geq l$ for all $k$. ($m, p, l \geq 0$ are given.)

**Attempt:** We can firstly give every $x$ $l$, then the problem becomes finding the number of partition of $m-pl$ with the number of summands no more than $p$, so the result is ${m-pl-1 \choose p-1}+{m-pl-1 \choose p-2}+...+{m-pl-1 \choose 0}$. Is this correct? If so, can I simplify this expression?

Comment: The number of weak compositions of $m-pl$ with $p$ parts is $\binom{m-p(l-1)-1}{p-1}=\binom{m-pl+p-1}{p-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about generating functions, the problem is to find the coefficient of $x^m$ in the generating function
$$A(x)=\left(x^l+x^{l+1}+\cdots\right)^p.$$

Note that

\begin{align}
A(x)&=x^{pl}(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^p\\
&=x^{pl}\frac{1}{(1-x)^p}\\
&=x^{pl}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{p+k-1}{p-1}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{p+k-1}{p-1}x^{pl+k}.
\end{align}

Observe that $m\geq pl$. (Otherwise the equation has no solution.). Thus, if $pl+k=m$,we have the solution
$$\binom{p+m-pl-1}{p-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

First you have to know the basic problem of counting solutions to $x_1 + \ldots + x_p = n$ where all $x_i \ge 0$ (and integer). This has $\binom{p + n -1}{p-1}$ many solutions (using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), e.g.)

So your idea of "giving $l$ to all $k$ bins/variables is sound, so you reduce to the number of solutions to $$x_1 +\ldots +x_p = m-lp, x_i \ge 0$$

which is by the first fact $\binom{p + (m-lp) - 1}{p-1}$ so one term, not a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
I think
$$x_1+ \cdots x_p =m$$

now drop $l$ to each $x_i$ and got

$$y_1+ \cdots y_p =m-pl$$ 
$y_i=x_i-l\geq 0$ now solve new equation.